# How to unversion an entire folder?

Tags: git

I have a folder versioned in a git. I want to unversion it, that is to remove the .git meta data, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933329

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If the folder is the top level of a git repository, and you actually want to completely remove the entire git repo associated with the folder, then simply delete the (hidden) `.git` directory from the folder:

```
cd foldername
rm -r .git
```

If the folder is a subdirectory of a git repository, then gautier's method is the one you want:

```
git rm --cached -r foldername/
```

Answer (score 24):

If you want to remove the files from git, but keep them in your filesystem add the option --cached.

```
git rm --cached -r foldername/
```

Answer (score 1):

`git rm -r foldername/`