# SVN - Can't undo revert

Tags: svn, version-control, ankhsvn, revision-history

OK, I just reverted a few hundreds of lines of good code. I know, I know. That's all my fault, nothing to do with SVN or any version control system. I just was very tired and very distracted and pressed the Revert button instead of the Commit one.

SVN (probably Ankh client) could do many things to protect the user from accidentally taking destructive actions. But I won't blame the tool, I assume the responsibility and I will pay that with my own time.

Now, I humbly ask your advice.

Should I do frequent commits? Even if the code is incomplete? Even if code won't run?

What about sandboxes? Are they used for the purpose of committing *in-dev* code?

On the other side, are there any simple local revision control software? Anything that watches the file system and records all changes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm a fan of creating SVN branches and doing frequent commits to my branch.  That keeps a clean trunk, but allows freedom to write many code iterations with freedom to revert as necessary.  I've learned not to keep my SVN branches not running too long while the trunk is changing as merging can be a headache - especially if there are changes to the tree structure.

With all of this being said, the organization I work for is going to switch to Git.

Apache posts what they consider to be some SVN best practices here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html

There's good infos in this post as well:
[Subversion Branch/Trunk Best Practice - keeping Branch Up-to-Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570071/subversion-branch-trunk-best-practice-keeping-branch-up-to-date)

Answer (score 1):

"local changes" that's where git shines.  Since git gives you a full repo locally, you can commit as often as possible which builds the log.

personally, when using svn, I always branch out and commit as often as I need.  Then I merge back to trunk when I'm done.  Of course, unlike with git, it requires that you have a connection to the remote svn repo.

Comment: I also like Git's ideas. When you push your local repo to a remote repo, does it send all the history of commits? Does'n it make the remote repo somewhat dirty?

Comment: It does, yes, but fortunately you can [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) your commits before you send them - you can collapse many commits into one (easy), break one commit into many (not that easy) and even reorder commits (perhaps too easy). You make your history look exactly the way you want it to look before sending it off to the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using fossil as a local repo to keep local history. Even it can be used as git I like to use it to keep my local files' history and move the repo to another machine when I need.

http://fossil-scm.org/

It is very small, no need to install anything (just 1 file) it has a tiny web server, wiki included etc.
Give it a try.